# Using python sounddevice query string to select device

Tags: python, audio, python-sounddevice

I'd like to select a particular sound device to use for audio input via python `sounddevice`.

The `sounddevice` docs make reference to using "query strings" to select devices (based on the devices "name" I'm pretty sure.) But I can't figure out how to formulate the query strings to work properly.

I know I can use `sounddevice.query_devices()` too see my device names, but how do I properly write these query strings to select my desired device?

(See the [`Stream` docs](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.5/api/streams.html#sounddevice.Stream) under the "device" parameter to see where it references query strings.)